# Picking a day from calendar - datepicker - from Protractor based on today's date

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor

We have a calendar that's built on bootstrap-datepicker. Am trying to pick a particular day, say, sysdate or sydate-2 or sysdate-3. One approach I came across is to use `findElements` and loop through the `List` till one of the element matches current date with `equalsIgnoreCase`.

But I want to achieve this in JS so as to use in my Protractor test cases.

Below is the structure of the table:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="day old disabled">30</td>
        <td class="day old disabled">31</td>
        <td class="day disabled">1</td>
        <td class="day disabled">2</td>
        <td class="day disabled">3</td>
        <td class="day disabled">4</td>
        <td class="day disabled">5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="day disabled">6</td>
        <td class="day disabled">7</td>
        <td class="day">8</td>
        <td class="day">9</td>
        <td class="day">10</td>
        <td class="day active today">11</td>
        <td class="day disabled">12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="day disabled">13</td>
        <td class="day disabled">14</td>
        <td class="day disabled">15</td>
        <td class="day disabled">16</td>
        <td class="day disabled">17</td>
        <td class="day disabled">18</td>
        <td class="day disabled">19</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="day disabled">20</td>
        <td class="day disabled">21</td>
        <td class="day disabled">22</td>
        <td class="day disabled">23</td>
        <td class="day disabled">24</td>
        <td class="day disabled">25</td>
        <td class="day disabled">26</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="day disabled">27</td>
        <td class="day disabled">28</td>
        <td class="day disabled">29</td>
        <td class="day disabled">30</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">1</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">2</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="day new disabled">4</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">5</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">6</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">7</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">8</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">9</td>
        <td class="day new disabled">10</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Instead of looping through all `td` elements,you can simply create a generic xpath or use `by.cssContainingText()` to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks, @SudharsanSelvaraj! Worked with `cssContainingText`.
`element(by.cssContainingText('.day', yesterDay)).click();`

Comment: Glad it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way is to enter the date manually, as in making protractor to enter the date in the input div instead of clicking a lot of things and making things complicated.

Suppose your input div is disabled for direct entry(that is, it has a disabled attribute) you can remove the disabled attribute by using plain javascript, like below:

```
 browser.executeScript('document.getElementsByName("dob0")[0].removeAttribute("disabled")');
 var date1 = 11 + '/' + 23 + '/' + 1994;
 dob.sendKeys(date1);
 browser.executeScript('document.getElementsByName("dob0")[0].setAttribute("disabled","disabled");');
```

And if you want to enter today's date, i suggeest you to use the [date object provided by javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Entering the date manually has been disabled. But as @Sudharsan has mentioned, will work with cssContainingTex().